# Copy each input row to the next available column

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have an excel file that has 3 columns A:C and I want to copy each row to the next available column.

[image]

I want to consolidate each row horizontally in a single row.

Comment: Could you please include the specific problem you had getting your attempt to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## ToRow in VBA

### Excel

- In Excel, you can use the formula

  ```
  =TOROW(A2:C4)
  ```

### VBA

- The `RangeToRow` function, which uses the `IsErrorBlankTestPassed` helper function, will mimic the Excel `TOROW` function entirely.
- If you don't have Microsoft 365, in Excel, you could use the function like this:

  ```
  =RangeToRow(A2:C4)
  ```

  Note that it is an array formula, so you'll have to confirm it with `Ctrl,Shift+Enter`.
  Also, note that there certainly are more appropriate formula solutions.

**The Test**

```vb
Sub RangeToRowTEST()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    ' Reference the source range.
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = ws.Range("A2:C4")
    
    ' Using the 'RangeToRow' function, return the values from the source range
    ' in a 1D one-based array.
    Dim Data(): Data = RangeToRow(srg) ' add other parameters
    If IsEmpty(Data) Then
        MsgBox "No valid values found.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
        
    ' Reference the destination range.
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = ws.Range("E2")
    Dim dcCount As Long: dcCount = UBound(Data)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dfCell.Resize(, dcCount)
    
    ' Write the values from the array to the destination range.
    drg.Value = Data ' write
    drg.Resize(, ws.Columns.Count - drg.Column - dcCount + 1) _
        .Offset(, dcCount).Clear ' clear to the right
    
End Sub
```

**The Main Function**

- The same function but for columns, `RangeToCol`, can be found [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75916513)

```vb
Function RangeToRow( _
    ByVal rg As Range, _
    Optional ByVal Ignore As Long = 0, _
    Optional ByVal ScanByColumn As Boolean = False) _
As Variant

    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = rg.Rows.Count
    Dim scCount As Long: scCount = rg.Columns.Count
    Dim drCount As Long: drCount = srCount * scCount
    
    Dim sData()
    
    If drCount = 1 Then
        ReDim sData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): sData(1, 1) = rg.Value
    Else
        sData = rg.Value
    End If
    
    Dim dData(): ReDim dData(1 To drCount)
    
    Dim sVal, sr As Long, sc As Long, dr As Long
    
    If ScanByColumn Then
        For sc = 1 To scCount
            For sr = 1 To srCount
                If IsErrorBlankTestPassed(sData(sr, sc), Ignore) Then
                    dr = dr + 1
                    dData(dr) = sData(sr, sc)
                End If
            Next sr
        Next sc
    Else
        For sr = 1 To srCount
            For sc = 1 To scCount
                If IsErrorBlankTestPassed(sData(sr, sc), Ignore) Then
                    dr = dr + 1
                    dData(dr) = sData(sr, sc)
                End If
            Next sc
        Next sr
    End If
    
    If drCount = 0 Then Exit Function ' only blanks and/or errors
    
    If dr < drCount Then ReDim Preserve dData(1 To dr)
    
    RangeToRow = dData

End Function
```

**The Helper Function**

```vb
Function IsErrorBlankTestPassed( _
    ByVal Value As Variant, _
    ByVal Ignore As Long) _
As Boolean
    Dim IsAddable As Boolean
    Select Case Ignore
        Case 0: IsAddable = True ' nothing
        Case 1: If Len(CStr(Value)) > 0 Then IsAddable = True ' blanks
        Case 2: If Not IsError(Value) Then IsAddable = True ' errors
        Case 3:
            If Not IsError(Value) Then ' blanks and errors
                If Len(CStr(Value)) > 0 Then IsAddable = True
            End If
    End Select
    IsErrorBlankTestPassed = IsAddable
End Function
```

Comment: In using the formula TOROW, can i add a condition where I only want to select all the rows that meets the condition that I want. For example torow only those in the First column that is equals to a.

Comment: Not sure if I understand: are you saying that you have Microsoft 365 and the `TOROW` (Excel) function and you don't want to return `d` and `4` in the resulting row? Either way, you have to combine it with some other functions.

Comment: yes that is correct, is their i way i can return a specific row or range in the resulting row

Comment: That is out of the scope of this question but it looks like you need something like, I'm guessing here, `=LET(Data,A2:C4,FILTER(Data,INDEX(Data,,1)="a",""))` which translates to return all rows whose first column is equal to "a". If you want the result stacked into a single row, you could wrap the `FILTER` into `TOROW`. But best ask another question with more detail possibly with screenshots of the before and the after. Also, additionally, add the `excel-formula` tag. It sounds fairly easy and if you ask correctly, with these new Excel functions, you may get multiple different answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with nested For loops. Loop through all 3 input columns in Row 1, repeat for Row 2, and repeat again for however many rows you have. The output is easier, it just goes to consecutive columns in Row 1.

Your question says you have 3 input columns, so the number of columns is fixed. You don't say whether the number of rows can vary. If so, the count can be determined with VBA. For this example I've set it to the 3 rows in your picture, just to keep it simple. With a lot of rows you'll need to Dim the row variables (nRow, nRowCount) to Long instead of Integer (for more than 32,767 rows).

```
Sub Transpose()
    Dim nColumnOut As Integer, nRow As Integer, nColumn As Integer, nRowCount As Integer, wkshSource As Worksheet

    Set wkshSource = ActiveSheet
    nRowCount = 3 ' Make this dynamic if needed
    nColumnOut = 6 ' First output column
    For nRow = 1 To nRowCount
        For nColumn = 1 To 3
            wkshSource.Cells(1, nColumnOut) = wkshSource.Cells(nRow, nColumn)
            nColumnOut = nColumnOut + 1  ' Move 1 column to the right
        Next nColumn
    Next nRow

End Sub
```