# Writing a range of values to an array

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a range of values to an array en masse.

```vb
Function buildArrayFromRange(inputArray As Variant) As String

Dim dynamicArray() As String
ReDim dynamicArray(inputArray.Cells.Count)

Dim x As Long
For Each cell In inputArray.Cells
    dynamicArray(x) = cell.Value
    x = x + 1
Next cell
  
buildArrayFromRange = dynamicArray
  
End Function
```

Now back in my calling Sub I want to write the result of `buildArrayFromRange` into a new array:

```vb
Dim xDRg1Array() As String

xDRg1Array = buildArrayFromRange(xDRg1)
```

I get a Compile error

> Can't assign to array at this point.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return array from function in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31564846/return-array-from-function-in-vba)

Comment: FYI your returned array is one element larger than the number of cells in the input range.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is returning an array of Strings, but you declared the function to return only a single String.

Not your problem, but not very clean: You expect that the input to the function is a Range (else you couldn't use `inputArray.Cells`), so you should declare it as `Range`, not as `Variant`. Use Variant only if you really don't know the type in advance.

So change your function declaration to

```
Function buildArrayFromRange(inputArray As Range) As String()
```

Answer (score 0):

### Range to String Array

- The following is similar to [ToCol in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75916513) which could be used to improve.

[image]

**Debug.Print Result**

```
4,9,3,7,8,5,40,24,28,30,23,25,22,21,27,11,15,20,16
```

**The Example**

```vb
Sub RangeToStringArrayTEST()

    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:B4,D1,C7:D10,D4:E5")
    
    Dim Arr() As String: Arr = RangeToStringArray(rg)
    
    If UBound(Arr) < LBound(Arr) Then
        MsgBox "No range referenced ('Nothing')." & vbLf _
            & "LB,UB [" & LBound(Arr) & "," & UBound(Arr) & "]" & vbLf _
            & "VarType: " & VarType(Arr) & vbLf _
            & "TypeName: " & TypeName(Arr), vbCritical
    Else
        'Debug.Print Join(Arr, ",")
        MsgBox Join(Arr, ",") & vbLf _
            & "LB,UB [" & LBound(Arr) & "," & UBound(Arr) & "]" & vbLf _
            & "VarType: " & VarType(Arr) & vbLf _
            & "TypeName: " & TypeName(Arr), vbInformation
    End If

End Sub
```

**The Function**

```vb
Function RangeToStringArray( _
    ByVal rg As Range, _
    Optional ByVal FirstIndex As Long = 0) _
As String()
    
    If rg Is Nothing Then
        RangeToStringArray = Split("")
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    Dim aCount As Long: aCount = rg.Areas.Count
    
    Dim sJag(): ReDim sJag(1 To aCount, 1 To 3)
    
    Dim arg As Range, sData(), a As Long
    Dim rCount As Long, cCount As Long, nCount As Long, tCount As Long
    
    For Each arg In rg.Areas
        a = a + 1
        rCount = arg.Rows.Count
        cCount = arg.Columns.Count
        nCount = rCount * cCount
        If nCount = 1 Then
            ReDim sData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): sData(1, 1) = arg.Value
        Else
            sData = arg.Value
        End If
        sJag(a, 1) = rCount
        sJag(a, 2) = cCount
        sJag(a, 3) = sData
        tCount = tCount + nCount
    Next arg
    
    Dim dn As Long: dn = FirstIndex - 1
    
    Dim dArr() As String: ReDim dArr(FirstIndex To tCount + dn)
    
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    
    For a = 1 To aCount
        For r = 1 To sJag(a, 1)
            cCount = sJag(a, 2)
            For c = 1 To cCount
                dn = dn + 1
                dArr(dn) = CStr(sJag(a, 3)(r, c))
            Next c
        Next r
    Next a
    
    RangeToStringArray = dArr

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

[@Funthomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7599798/funthomas) is right about your function returning a string, not an array.

If you have the range you can just convert it to an array. There is no need to read each cell from the sheet in a loop as VBA is very inefficient when accessing worksheets repeatedly.

```
Function buildArrayFromRange(inputRange As Range) As Variant()
  
    buildArrayFromRange = inputRange.value
  
End Function
```

Comment: That's not gonna work because `inputRange.Value`, if the range consists of at least two cells, will return a `Variant` array.

Comment: You're right, an oversight on my part. This only works if the function is set to as Variant(). Editing my answer to reflect this.